# Añadir una clase con una propiedad css alterada por evento jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un evento jquery que actúa cuando el scroll está a una determinada altura cambiando algunas propiedades css de la clase que añaden los botones Blur Gradient. Lo que ocurre cuando pulso el botón es que añade la clase PERO con las propiedades css por defecto y no las que están fijadas para la posición de scroll en la que nos encontramos.

**EDIT**
He simplificado el código para que sea más facil de entender; hay 3 funciones principales:
- Función de difuminado [añade la prop. -webkit-text-stroke-color añadiendo una clase a los divs]
- Cambio de Color en la letra C [cambia propiedad css]
- Cambios de color en Scroll  [cambia varias propiedades css]

El problema se divide en dos fases:
 - Cuando la propiedad css cambia por el scroll, al pulsar el botón de "Blur" añade las clases apropiadas para difuminar las letras PERO, con el valor de la propiedad css sin alterar hasta que vuelvo a realizar scroll.
 - Lo mismo ocurre cuando tras cambiar el color de la letra C pulsando en uno de los botones de la tira de colores; cambio el botón que está pulsado en el difuminado; el valor de difuminado del color alterado NO cambia.

```js
//FUNCION DIFUMINAR 
 //BIBLIO
 
function removeBlur1() {
$('.position').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position').removeClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('ablur4');
}
function removeBlur2() {
$('.position').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position').removeClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('bblur4');
}
function removeBlur3() {
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
}

 //ACCiÓN
 
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#1blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
removeBlur1();
removeBlur2();
removeBlur3();
})
$('#2blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur1');
$('.position2').addClass('blur1');
$('.position3').addClass('blur1');
$('.position4').addClass('blur1');
$('.position').addClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').addClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').addClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').addClass('ablur4');
removeBlur2();
removeBlur3();
})
$('#3blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur2');
$('.position2').addClass('blur2');
$('.position3').addClass('blur2');
$('.position4').addClass('blur2');
$('.position').addClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').addClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').addClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').addClass('bblur4');
removeBlur1();
removeBlur3();
})
$('#4blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur3');
$('.position2').addClass('blur3');
$('.position3').addClass('blur3');
$('.position4').addClass('blur3');
$('.position').addClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').addClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').addClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').addClass('cblur4');
removeBlur1();
removeBlur2();
})
});
//FUNCIÓN DE CAMBIOS DE COLOR EN CLICK

var enable = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#enable').click(function () {
  if (!enable) {
    enable = true;
 $('#enable').css({
 'border':'white 2px solid',
 'width':'20px',
 'height':'20px',
 'opacity':'1'
 });
 $('.disable').css({
 'border':'none',
 'width':'24px',
 'height':'24px'
 });
    animateIt();
  }
})
});
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.disable').click(function () {
  enable = false;
  var color=$('.position').css('color');
$('#p1color').html(color);
})
});
function removeRed() {
$('#layer1_red').css({
'border':'none',
'width':'24px',
'height':'24px'
});
}
function removeGreen() {
$('#layer1_green').css({
'border':'none',
'width':'24px',
'height':'24px'
});
}
function removeCyan() {
$('#layer1_cyan').css({
'border':'none',
'width':'24px',
'height':'24px'
});
}
function removeYellow() {
$('#layer1_yellow').css({
'border':'none',
'width':'24px',
'height':'24px'
});
}
function removePerimeter() {
$('#enable').css({
'border':'1px white solid',
'width':'22px',
'height':'22px',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
}
function addcodeColor3() {
var color=$('.position3').css('color');
$('#p3color').html(color); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#layer1_yellow').click(function () {
$('.position3').css('color','rgba(251,255,0,1.00)');
$('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(251,255,0,1.00)',
});
$('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(251,255,0,0.20)',
});
$('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(251,255,0,0.05)',
});
$(this).css({
'border':'white 2px solid',
'width':'20px',
'height':'20px'
});
removePerimeter();
removeCyan();
removeGreen();
removeRed();
addcodeColor3(); 
})
$('#layer1_cyan').click(function () {
$('.position3').css('color','rgba(0,247,255,1.00)');
$('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,247,255,1.00)',
});
$('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,247,255,0.20)',
});
$('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,247,255,0.05)',
});
$(this).css({
'border':'white 2px solid',
'width':'20px',
'height':'20px'
});
removeYellow();
removeGreen();
removeRed();
removePerimeter();
addcodeColor3();
})
$('#layer1_red').click(function () {
$('.position3').css('color','rgba(255,0,4,1.00)');
$('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,0,4,1.00)',
});
$('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,0,4,0.20)',
});
$('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,0,4,0.05)',
});
$(this).css({
'border':'white 2px solid',
'width':'20px',
'height':'20px'
});
removeYellow();
removeGreen();
removeCyan();
removePerimeter();
addcodeColor3(); 
})
$('#layer1_green').click(function () { 
$('.position3').css('color','rgba(0,255,12,1.00)');
$('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,255,12,1.00)',
});
$('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,255,12,0.20)',
});
$('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(0,255,12,0.05)',
});

$(this).css({
'border':'white 2px solid',
'width':'20px',
'height':'20px'
});
removeYellow();
removeRed();
removeCyan();
removePerimeter();
addcodeColor3();
});
})
// FUNCIÓN DE CAMBIOS EN SCROLL

var enable = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#enable').click(function () {
  if (!enable) {
    enable = true;
 $('#enable').css({
 'border':'white 2px solid',
 'width':'20px',
 'height':'20px',
 'opacity':'1'
 });
 $('.disable').css({
 'border':'none',
 'width':'24px',
 'height':'24px'
 });
    animateIt();
  }
})
});
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.disable').click(function () {
  enable = false;
  var color=$('.position').css('color');
$('#p1color').html(color);
})
});
function animateIt() {
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
 if (!enable) return;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(72,145,0,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.05)'
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(229,200,96,1.00)'
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.05)'
   })
 
  }
   if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(52,52,52,1.00)'
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.05)'
   })
  }
   });
}
animateIt();
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(186,153,82,1.00)',
'background':'none'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(239,240,207,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(235,246,177,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,0.05)',
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,0.05)',
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,0.05)',
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(68,25,16,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(246,246,248,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(218,149,20,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)','color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.05)'
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(108,69,48,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(214,193,165,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(18,124,23,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)','color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.05)'
   })
  }
   });
```

```css
body{padding:0; margin:0;background:black; height:3000px;}
#layer1{width:700px; height:700px;  margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:5; text-align:center; top:0px;}
#layer2{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:10; text-align:center;top:20px;}
#layer3{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:15; text-align:center;top:40px;}
#layer4{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:6; text-align:center;top:60px;}
.position{
background:black;
color:rgba(186,153,82,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono; 
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:30px;

}
.position2{
color:rgba(239,240,207,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono;  
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:30px;
}
.position3{
color:rgba(72,145,0,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono; 
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:30px;

}
.position4{
color:rgba(235,246,177,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono;  
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:30px;

}
.pcolor{
color:white;
font-size:11px;
}
.disable{width:24px; height:24px; display:inline-block;float:left;cursor:pointer;}
#enable{width:20px; height:20px; border:white 2px solid; font-size:7px; color:white; text-align:center; line-height:20px; cursor:pointer; float:left; display:inline-block;}
#layer1_options{position:fixed; z-index:100; margin-top:100px; left:30px; padding:0; font-size:10px; color:white; text-align:left;}
#layer1_yellow{background:yellow;}
#layer1_red{background:red;}
#layer1_cyan{background:cyan;}
#layer1_green{background:rgba(0,255,12,1.00);}
.addblur{width:28px; height:28px; display:inline-block;float:left;cursor:pointer; padding:0; font-size:10px; color:white; line-height:28px; text-align:center;border-right:white 1px solid; background:rgba(217,217,217,1.00); opacity:1; z-index:100;}
#blur_bar{border: 2px white solid; position:fixed;}
.blur1{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px; 
 }
.blur2{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 10px; 
 }
.blur3{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 25px; 
 }
 .ablur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,1.0);
}
.ablur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,1.0);
}
.ablur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,1.0);
}
.ablur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,1.0);
}
.bblur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,0.2);
}
.bblur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,0.2);
}
.bblur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,0.2);
}
.bblur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,0.2);
}
.cblur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,0.05);
color:rgba(186,153,82,0.2);
}
.cblur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,0.05);
color:rgba(239,240,207,0.05);
}
.cblur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,0.05);
color:rgba(72,145,0,0.05);
}
.cblur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,0.05);
color:rgba(235,246,177,0.05);
}
#blur_options{ width:120px; height:30px; margin-top:30px; position:fixed; z-index:200; left:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer1">
<pre class="position">
A
</pre>
</div>

<div id="layer2">
<pre class="position2">
B
</pre>
</div>

<div id="layer3">
<pre class="position3">
C
</pre>
</div>

<div id="layer4">
<pre class="position4">
D
</pre>
</div>
<div id="layer1_options">
<h1 style="top:0; font-size:10px; font-weight:100; padding:0; line-height:5px;">Fixed Colors 1</h1>
<div id="enable">
AUTO
</div>
<div class="disable" id="layer1_yellow">
</div>
<div class="disable" id="layer1_red">
</div>
<div class="disable" id="layer1_cyan">
</div>
<div class="disable" id="layer1_green">
</div>
</div>

<div id="blur_options">
<h1 style="top:0; font-size:10px; font-weight:100; padding:0; line-height:8px; color:white; ">Blur <br>
</h1>
<div id="blur_bar">
<div class="addblur" id="1blur">0%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="2blur" style="opacity:0.5">33%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="3blur" style="opacity:0.5">66%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="4blur" style="opacity:0.5">99%</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: El código de arriba se podría (y debería) simplificar considerablemente para hacerlo más fácil de entender y mantener

Comment: Lo sé @AlvaroMontoro pero como siempre estoy limitado de conocimientos y tampoco quiero abarrotar el foro con cada una de mis cuestiones por eso cuando funciona aunque no me convenza tiro para adelante...

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo seguiría la recomendación de @AlvaroMontoro y limpiaría el código, a la larga te vas a beneficiar y entenderás mejor todo lo que está pasando.

---

Ahora vamos a tú problema: lo que te pasa es que estas sobreescribiendo las propiedades ya que no recoges los valores simplemente los asignas.

```
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
```

He preparado un pequeño ejemplo que creo que te puede ayudar a entenderlo en el que con botones aumentas o reduces el tamaño de un texto, respetando el tamaño que tiene.

```js
function mas() {
  // recogemos el tamaño ACTUAL de la fuente
  var size = $("#ejemplo").css("font-size");
  // parseamos y aumentamos el tamaño ACTUAL de la fuente 
  var newSize = parseInt(size.substring(0, size.length - 2)) + 2;
  // insertamos el valor actualizado
  $("#ejemplo").css("font-size", newSize);
}

function menos() {
  // recogemos el tamaño ACTUAL de la fuente
  var size = $("#ejemplo").css("font-size");
  // parseamos y reducimos el tamaño ACTUAL de la fuente 
  var newSize = parseInt(size.substring(0, size.length - 2)) - 2;
  // insertamos el valor actualizado
  $("#ejemplo").css("font-size", newSize);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ejemplo">
  HOLA MUNDO
</div>

<button id="mas" onclick="mas()">+</button>
<button id="menos" onclick="menos()">-</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora el problema es cómo consigo el valor de la propiedad css "--webkit-text-stroke-color?

Comment: Puedes montar una demo para poder reproducir tu problema e intentar solucionarlo?

Comment: He hecho caso a @alvaromontoro y he simpflicado lo más posible para mis conocimientos el código y he editado la pregunta para dejarlo todo mucho más claro  espero que así sea más fácil ayudarme :)

Comment: como me dijiste he introducido una demo más detallada y un edit para aclarar más la pregunta :)